# suspendEvents on checkbox does not work

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

I am setting a checkbox programmatically,

since I am setting it dynamically I want to suspend (change event) the events on it, because on change of checkbox i have some other things to be performed.

I already tried using the following code but it does not work.

```
checkbox.suspendEvents(false);
checkbox.setValue(true);
checkbox.resumeEvents();
```

Thanks

Comment: in what way is it not working?

Comment: it does not suspend events for the checkbox

Answer (score 8, accepted):

checkbox.[setRawValue](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Checkbox-method-setRawValue)(true); method won't trigger change event.

Looks like an extjs [bug](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?263404-Checkbox-does-not-fire-quot-change-quot-event-on-the-first-change-after-setRawValue(true)./page2), workaround is to set `checkbox.lastValue = true;` along with setRawValue in-order to detect the next change event.

Comment: this is not working, it sets the checkbox properly but when i uncheck it doesn't listen to change event which results in loss of functionality. anyways thanks for the reply

Comment: In my case, this one worked: checkbox.lastValue = false; checkbox.setValue(false);. I dont want to trigger onChange event when I reset the checkbox so, for that particular method I set lastValue as false and then call setValue(false). The problem with setRawValue() is; it does not trigger the onChange event method when you click on the checkbox for the first time after calling setRawValue(). It works for the second time and so on.

Answer (score 2):

The suspendEvent event bug is there for comboboxes too. Here are the bug reports:

- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?171525-suspendEvents-did-not-affect-to-Ext.app.Controller.control
- http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?232919-ComboBox-suspendEvents-doesn-t-work

I found a solution that fixes it for comboboxes. Maybe the solution works for checkboxes too. It works in Ext JS 4.2.1. Maybe other versions too.

```
checkbox.suspendCheckChange++;
checkbox.setValue(true);
checkbox.suspendCheckChange--;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there dosen't appear to be anything wrong with your code have you tried:

```
checkbox.suspendEvent('change');
checkbox.setValue(true);
checkbox.resumeEvent('change');
```

Comment: Works for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

The suspendEvent and resumeEvent is not applied for event listeners defined in the controller, only on event listeners directly on the component.

newmount's solution is the best workaround

Answer (score 0):

If you are.looking to reset the value to what it was (say on failure to validate or save).

checkbox.reset ();

Works fine in extjs 4.2.2